# Send data from Client to Client within localhost with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I want to make a connect four game with the option to play online against another person connected to my game which is hosted through localhost (within the same WiFi). It's possible to play a game on both computers but not against each other.

Firstly I want to get a simple string send from one client to the other with an ajax call. My attempt:

```
$(".column").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: "GetBoard",
          method: "GET",
          data: { "currentplayer" : currentPlayer },
          success: function (data) {
              alert("success");
          }
      });
)};
```

The controller method I used:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetBoard(string currentPlayer)
{
    return View(currentPlayer);
}
```

I don't really understand how to send data with ajax or how to receive and work with it within a controller.

Comment: [HttpPost], method: "GET", do you see any difference? :)

Comment: And better to use websockets for such case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make application available over wifi network you can do these steps.

**Step#1**

[Publish](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/francissvk/how-to-hosting-Asp-Net-mvc-web-application-in-local-machine/) you application on local host so that if other user is on same network then they can browse the local host using listening port.
Example: localhost:8733

**Step#2**

You can use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) to broadcast changes in game real time so that other users on same local host will be able see the changes.

**Example**

If you want to broadcast move of particular Id then you can create you hub class like this

```
 public class GameHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string move, int Id)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(move,Id);
    }
}
```

**Html**

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

     //this will write to page
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (move, Id) {

        console.log("New move "+move);
                console.log("New Id "+Id);

        };


        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   //this will broadcast move to all pages
            $('#broadcast').click(function () {
                 chat.server.send($('#currentmove').val(), $('#currentId').val());

            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much! this was the answer i was looking for!

Comment: glad to help you.